# how to solve special equations in octave

Tags: matlab, octave

I've got a porblem. I'm new in Octave need to solve these equations in this format:

`-397.95 = min(k1*rate + k2); 
776.37 = max(k1*rate + k2);`

where rate is my row vector at size 10000. All I need is octave function which can deal with roots which are in other function (in my max and min). I know, that this question is a little bit mathematical, but I can't get the right easy function for solving this...

Thank you for answer

Comment: You description doesn't look clear. Are k1 and k2 vectors too?

Comment: Hello sorry that I didn't write it... no k1 and k2 are constants and they are roots of my equations. k1 and k2 are numbers which I have to find

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to use an optimization to minimise a cost function which would look like:

```
function y = f(x)

   % k1 is x(1), k2 is x(2)
   rate = ...
   y = [min(x(1)*rate + x(2))+397.95; max(x(1)*rate+x(2))-776.37]

end
```

You can then use optimization functions such as `fminsearch` or other (from the `optim` package). The idea is to try and minimize your cost function, i.e. get `y` towards 0. It might be a good idea to use `abs` in your function to avoid issue with negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to see that the constraints for this problem are:

```
k1 * rate + k2 >= -397.95
```

and

```
k1 * rate + k2 <= 776.37
```

Since larger values of k1 give a larger variance in the result of this equation, your objective is to maximize k1 subject to these constraints (equivalently minimize -k1).

You can now run this as a simple linear program:

```
height = size(rate,1);
c = [-1;0];
A = [rate',ones(height,1); rate',ones(height,1)];
b = [-397.95*ones(height,1); 766.37*ones(height,1)];
lb = [0;-Inf];
ub = [Inf; Inf];
ctype = [repmat("L",height,1); repmat("U",height,1)];
k = glpk (c,A,b,lb,ub,ctype)
k1 = k(1);
k2 = k(2);
```

EDIT : I missed that rate was a row vector.  I've transposed it appropriately

Answer (score 0):

Actually since there are only two variables, this can be solved directly.  Assuming k1 is positive (No reason not to make k1 positive since flipping the sign doesn't really change the problem since k2 can be shifted appropriately), then we have k1*max(rate) + k2 = 776.37 and k1*min(rate) + k2 = -397.95

So

```
k1*(max(rate) - min(rate)) = 776.37 - (-397.95)
```

Then we can solve for k1 as

```
k1 = (776.37 - (-397.95))/(max(rate) - min(rate))
```

And then k2 can be found as

```
k2 = 776.37 - k1 * max(rate)
```